# Binding partial view data to Main view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial inside my main view, this partial view gets populated once the "Click Me" button is clicked. Now my question is , how do I bind the partial view model back to main model ?

This is my parent view looks like

```
@model TestModel       

@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "GetQuote", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "loader-disabled-next", role = "form", id = "frmtest" }))
    {

        <fieldset class="fieldset-border loader" >
            <legend class="fieldset-border fieldset-header">Find Your locations</legend>
           <div>
            @Html   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>
       <button type="button" id="click">Click Me!</button>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset  class="fieldset-border loader" >
            <legend class="fieldset-border fieldset-header">YOUR BUSINESS LOCATION(S)</legend>

            <div id="BusinessLocations">
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                    @Html.Partial("_BusinessLocationResults", Model.Addresses)

                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
}

this is how the partial code looks like
@model IEnumerable<BusinessAddress>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col">
            <fieldset class="fieldset-border loader">

                <p class="funnel-your-business">

                    <span id="address-address1">
                        @item.Address1
                    </span>
                    <br />                    
                    <span id="address-citystate">
                        @({item.State}")
                    </span>

                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
```

This is my viewmodel definition
View Model

```
public class TestModel
{
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string List<BusinessAddress> Addresses {get;set;}
}
public class BusinessAddress 
{
 public string Address1 {get;set;}
 public string State {get;set;}

}



Public ActionResult LoadData()
{
 var model = new TestModel();
 model.FirstName = "sssss";
 model.Addresses = new List<BusinessAddress>();
return view("TestBusiness",model);
}
```

Here is the action method that returns data for partial view

```
public PartialViewResult SaveClickMe(string firstname)
{
var model = new List<BusinessAddress>();
  //logic to create and populate list of Business address
  //model has data at this point

return PartialView("partialaddview",model);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean _bind the partial view model back to main model_? And where is your script that making the ajax call to your `SaveClickMe` to populate the data and update the DOM? And what is the point of your `@Html.Partial()` when it initially contains no data?

Answer (score 0):

When you post data to the server (I mean, an `action` into a `controller`), you can bind it into a `class`. If you want to send data back to the `View`, you can just return it from the `Action` (from a `Controller`.

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult TestAction(TestModel input)
{
   // some code/validation

   // return the same view but with the TestModel you bind from view to a view again!
   return View(input);
}
```

Your `Partial View` will just render, but you didn't send information from there. You could just add `hidden` inputs to provide the information and bind it as a `indexed collection` on the target property (`Addresses` on your case). For sample:

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessAddress>
@{ 
   int index = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    @Html.Hidden("Addresses[" + index + "].Address1", item.Address1)
    @Html.Hidden("Addresses[" + index + "].State", item.State)

    index++;

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col">
        <fieldset class="fieldset-border loader">

            <p class="funnel-your-business">                    

                <span id="address-address1">
                    @item.Address1
                </span>
                <br />                    
                <span id="address-citystate">
                    @({item.State}")
                </span>

            </p>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: My only suggestion would be if you wanted to go the hidden input route, might as well cut down on the extra lines of bracket razor and tracking the index yourself, just use a for to have it done and tracked for you on one line. Small but when you are flipping through lots of embedded razor syntax, every clear line helps.

Comment: ok, I use hidden inputs to provide information but how do I bind it as an indexed collection ? I have to initialise the list in cshtml ? or call another partial that returns empty object and then assign information ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in this case since you are looking for two way binding easily, you use an `EditorFor`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Addresses, "BusinessLocationResults")
```

Then put the simple partial inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BusinessLocationResults.cshtml` or inside `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/BusinessLocationResults.cshtml` where `Home` is the name of your controller

The Razor engine will look for and find a view that matches the name of the "item" class. When it does, it will iterate through the collection, generating a row for each item in your address enumerable. This means you will remove your loop inside the partial code now.

As a side effect and the real benefit that you are looking for, it also names the controls in such a way that the collection can be posted to the controller in a manner that the default model binder understands.